# Can I change the maximum value for the index during a for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers

I have this for loop:

```
    for (i = 0; i < totaltri; ++i) {
        triptr = &(trilist[i]);
        pt1ptr = &(triptr->corner[0]);
        struct point t1 = { pt1ptr->x, pt1ptr->y, pt1ptr->z };
        pt2ptr = &(triptr->corner[1]);
        struct point t2 = { pt2ptr->x, pt2ptr->y, pt2ptr->z };
        pt3ptr = &(triptr->corner[2]);
        struct point t3 = { pt3ptr->x, pt3ptr->y, pt3ptr->z };
        cutorthrow(p, t1, t2, t3, v, i);
        printf("TRIANGLE NUMBER: %d\n", i + 1);
    }
```

However, the number `totaltri` sometimes becomes `totaltri-1` (if the triangle has been deleted).
Is it possible to be able to change the value of `totaltri`? OR perhaps put a pointer to the number (if so, when and how would I reference it?)

Comment: Yes, you can change the value of `totaltri`. Simply assign to that as usual.

Comment: My for loop doesn’t finish though...! So I assumed it was a problem with the fact that totaltri doesn’t match up?

Comment: @MikeCAT ^ :) forgot!

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: For example: a for loop that has a maximum number of say 20, however if something is the case within that for loop, the maximum number reduces by 1 :) the thing is that this happens on some loops but not others. @MikeCAT

Answer (score 1):

The expressions in a `for` loop are not required to be in a particular form; you may use any expressions, subject to the usual C rules (or, for the first item, a declaration).

`for (i = 0; i < totaltri; ++i)` is a way of writing a loop to iterate from 0 to `totaltri`. You are not required to use that form or to hold `totaltri` constant. The test condition `i < totaltri` will be executed each time the loop iterates. The value of `totaltri` is not memorized and held constant. You can use arbitrary expressions as test conditions, including functions, as in `for (i = CalculateStartPoint(stuff); TestWhetherLoopIsDone(i, stuff); UpdateIterator(&i))`.

However, if you are going to reduce `totaltri` during the loop, you need to be careful about what happens if `i` is already past the new limit. Is the current iteration going to work the way you want it to in that case?